# How to build V8 for armv7

Tags: ios, arm, v8

i'm trying to use Google's v8 in my iPhone Application. 
I built the libraries using "make arm" as stated on Google's website.
Unfortunately I get several linker errors telling me that the library is build "for archive".

The terminal tells me that the library's architecture is i386:

```
lipo -info  libv8_base.a
input file libv8_base.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libv8_base.a is architecture: i386
```

So, how do I actually build a armv7 library?

BTW: I don't really know much about this library building stuff. Maybe I can only build for ARM on an actual ARM device? I don't get why I can't just download the prebuilt files anywhere, too.

Comment: V8 is a just-in-time compiler. This will not be allowed in the AppStore (hence why Google's own Chrome app for iOS does not use V8).

Comment: okay, but i'd still like to know what's the issue..

Answer (score 0):

You can find instructions to cross-compile for ARM on the [v8 wiki](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/CrossCompilingForARM).

When running on an x86 machine

```
make arm
```

builds a simulator, not an actual ARM binary.

You can also compile a release shell natively if you have ARM hardware:

```
scons arch=arm -j2
```

EDIT:
You may also want to learn about [cross-compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

Answer (score 0):

There is a simulator for armv7 built in the v8 source. If you check v8/src/arm/ you will find simulator files. 
To build, make sure your CC, CXX and LINK are point to native gcc / g++ tools. And then do

```
Make arm.release -j8
```

This will make for arm and look into *.gypi files for more build options. Hope this is useful.